# CSS 100% width is more that 100%

Tags: html, css, layout, width, stylesheet

I'm learning CSS and I tried to create a simple layout.

I set the "header" to have a width of 100%, the "left" to have a width of 20% and the "right" 80%. But the width of the header is greater than the total width of the left and the right. Why is that and how to fix it?

```css
    div {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    #header {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #80B7ED;
        height: 50px;
     width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    .left {
        background-color: #5A9DE0;
        height: 400px;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .right {
        background-color: #BFD9F2;
        height: 400px;
        width: 80%;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #footer {
        background-color: #80B7ED;
        clear: both;
        height:70px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
      <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="header">
         </div>
         <div class="left">
         </div>
         <div class="right">
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
         </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit**

Thanks to your answers and to some reading I get now that the problem is the margin of the body section. When I use body {margin: 0;} the "left" plus the "right" take a bigger place in the page and the "header" takes a smaller place, so their widths are equal.

Another solution with the same result is adding a "container" div around everything with "left: 0; right: 0; position: absolute;".

I understand why these solutions make the "left" plus the "right" bigger (so they take the whole page), what I don't get is **why the "header" is suddenly smaller**. If the fixed "header" is out of the regular flow, why changing the margin of the body influeces it?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#header {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #80B7ED;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.left {
    background-color: #5A9DE0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.right {
    background-color: #BFD9F2;
    height: 400px;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #80B7ED;
    clear: both;
    height:70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: margins - that's not included in the width calculation by default. e.g. a box's full width is leftmargin + leftpadding + box width + rightpadding + rightmargin.

Comment: @MarcB there are no margins involved here ? But indeed that is a classic too

Comment: there's always default margins, unless you're using a CSS reset somewhere.

Comment: This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) will help you understand more about CSS box models

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; to the div selector and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the question. Why was the width of the header bigger than the whole page?

Comment: @Ella Shar: In answer to your latest question, the width of the header is calculated **before** the margins on the body are applied, because it's positioning is `fixed`. Read my latest edit on my answer if you wish to be able to apply margins and get the header calculation right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
}
div {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
    padding: 0%;
}
#wrap {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    position:fixed;
    width:inherit;
    z-index:1;
    padding:0px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color: #80B7ED;
}
.left {
    background-color: #5A9DE0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.right {
    background-color: #BFD9F2;
    height: 400px;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #80B7ED;
    clear: both;
    height:70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

See here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbLhmzz/)

**EDIT**:

If you wish to add a margin, I'd suggest you add a **variable margin**, for instance 2% or 3%, and then you substract that quantity from the left column, the right column, or both. And then you set the width of the `#wrapp` to be 100-2*x %, where x is the amount of margin you added.

Comment: Oops.... just realized it works on jsfiddle but not here. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Doesn't work in my browser either (firefox).. thanks

Comment: I don't know why it is working in jsfiddle though... I'll keep investigating.

Comment: Allright, I have the final solution. Turns out @Jmh2013 was right, there is a default margin applied to the body. Adding `margin: 0px;` to the body in css fixes the problem.

Answer (score 9):

When using percentage widths the `margin`, `padding` and `border` are not included in the calculation. So you want to be sure all of those are set to 0 on the corresponding elements.

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
```

Alternatively, you could use the `box-sizing` property which will make the calculation include `padding` and `border`. Then you would only have to account for the margins elsewhere.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Not what he's asking. He has no margins, paddings or borders set in his css. See here http://jsfiddle.net/u3r2bm47/

Comment: I want the position to be fixed so the header remains when the page is scrolled.

Comment: hmm. That is not easily done and I doubt there will be a clean cross browser solution. Could you just set the width on the header instead of using percentage? If you need it responsive, you could use Javascript to check the width of the main section and set it to be equal.. Kinda hacky.. but it would work.

Comment: hmmm I could do that.. I'm just curious, why it doesn't work when I set the width to 100% and the position to fixed

Comment: Because when you set the position to fixed, it takes that element out of the flow so it no longer is constrained by any other elements. Its only container is now the viewport and all others no longer exist as far as it is concerned. Here is the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning). Might be worth a quick read.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `overflow: hidden;` for parent div and set `width:100%;` for the child element. This way, more width will be hidden.